# Duplicate entry '6343' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

I've begun receiving the above error when trying to add a record to a database.
The column in question is set to 'auto_increment' and is of datatype 'INT' with a length of 10.

Looking around online I can see that this error can occur when an auto incremented column reached its upper limit - however in this instance the table only contains 6342 records, and the column should be able to hold much more.

Indeed, the application in question is used in several installations and in some cases the equivalent table with an identical structure has many more records than this without generating an error.

Stranger still, when I changed the datatype of this column to 'BIGINT', it resolved the issue - even though on other installations it remains the same with more records.

Can anyone suggest any reasons why this issue may have occurred?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what if you change the data type back to INT?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@auto_increment_increment` return on the problematic instance?

Comment: I've changed the data type back to INT and it continues to work without a problem.

Comment: SELECT @@auto_increment_increment returns '1'

Comment: What does SELECT auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='YOUR_TABLE'; return? I doubt this will be 1.

Comment: While you're at it try and run this and see if anything changes.
optimize table YOUR_TABLE;

Comment: That came back with 6349 - which is currently the next ID to be added for a new row.

Comment: When I looked online for a solution, some people recommended optimizing - however the issue isn't currently happening, so I won't be able to tell if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `auto_increment_offset` server variable somehow got set to 6343.  You can find more information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset).

Comment: I checked, but auto_increment_offset is set to '1'. Also, all the installations of this app are running from on the same server, but with different databases. So any server-wide setting would affect them all.